Prove that $x^3 + 3x^2 + 16$ has exactly one real root
I have to prove that $ f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 16$ has exactly one real root. Being a polynomial, function is continuous over any closed interval and differentiable over any open interval. Now, $f(-5) < 0 < f(-3) $. So, by intermediate value theorem, there is at least one root in $(-5, -3)$. To prove with contradiction, now suppose that there are two distinct real roots, $a$ and $b$. I can assume here that $a < b$. Then $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ since these are roots. By Rolle's theorem, there is a $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$
$$ f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} = 0 $$
Now, $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 6x$. Hence, solving above equation gives us $c = 0$ or $c = -2$. It can be seen that $f(0) = 16$ and $f(-2) = 20$. I want to reach some contradiction but I don't see it yet. I have seen this question answered elsewhere on this forum, but could not understand the solution.

I have read a bunch of answers here. But how do I reach a contradiction here ? I think this is the common thread in such problems

The contradiction is that in $[-2,0]$ $f'(x)\le 0$ and that for $x\ge 0$ $f'(x)\ge 0$ but this is not related to Roll's theorem.

so function is increasing for $x \leq -2$, so there can't be more than one root for $x < -2$. On $[-2,0]$ , absolute maxima and absolute minima are at endpoints and they are not zero. So, there is no root in $[-2,0]$. For $x \geq 0 $, function is increasing, so $f(x) \geq f(0) $. Hence there can't be root when $x \geq 0$. This means that there is only one real root.

Yes but this result can be obtained using IVT and monotonicity.

Did any of the four answers help you? If not, why don't you at least tell us what other answers you looked at (or at least what questions they were attached to) so that people know what not to tell you? Or did you just answer your own question in a comment?

As $x=0$ is not a root, you can consider the reverse polynomial
$$
g(z)=16z^3+3z+1.
$$
This now has a derivative $48z^2+3$ that is obviously always positive, so that $g$ is strictly monotonic and thus has exactly one real root.

I have never seen this technique of using reverse polynomial in Calculus courses. Can you give references so that I can learn more about it ?

Relating the properties like the root set of $f(x)$ and $g(z)=z^{\deg f}f(z^{-1})$ is often done. It should be found applied in any book on the computer algebra and numerical algebra of polynomials. I do not have directly a title.

From Descartes' Rule of Signs no real roots of $f(x)=x^3+3x^2+16$ can be positive, so all three real roots of $f(-x)=-x^3+3x^2+16=0$ would have to be positive. But the Rule of Signs allows only one positive root for the latter equation $\rightarrow\leftarrow$.

Lutz's answer is very nice. Another way is to notice that $x=-4$ is a root, so we can factorise $f$ as
$$x^3+3x^2+16=(x+4)(x^2-x+4)$$
and the discriminant of $x^2-x+4$ is negative, so it has no real roots.

$f(x)=x^2(x+3) + 16$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,-3)$ and positive on $[-3,+\infty)$. Hence it has only one real root.
